# How to push all key/value pairs to object from forEach

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I'm running my array of objects (this.state.exportEntries) through a for loop that is then comparing the itemId to the key within the object returned within the for loop. If the key matches itemId, then run a forEach to push that key/value to the filteredData object.

My issue is that, if I have more than one value that matches, the forEach only pushes the last returned value to the filteredData object.

Could anyone help me understand how to push all returned values to the filteredData object? As you can see in the output of this.state.filteredData, only the last key/value pair that is matched gets pushed to filteredData.

**Code Structure**

```
for (let item of this.state.exportEntries) {

  console.log(item);

  Object.entries(item)
    .filter(([key,]) => key === itemId)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => (this.state.filteredData[key] = value));

}

console.log(this.state.filteredData);
```

**Output of item**

```
{1.2: "1", 1.3: "1"}

{1.2: "2", 1.3: "2"}

{1.2: "3", 1.3: "3"}

{1.2: "4", 1.3: "4"}
```

**Output of this.state.filteredData**

```
{1.3: "4"}
```

**Desired Result**

```
{
 1.3: "1, 2, 3, 4"
}
```

Comment: `push` is for Arrays.
You want to add `key:value`s to an Object?
`object(key)=value`.
If `key` already exists, it will be overwritten.
You could check for that and change `value` to an Array and add the new `value`, for example.

Comment: what output would you actually want? In `this.state.filteredData[key] = value`, you have ensured by the `filter` above (which can only ever return an array of at most one element), that the only value that ever gets updated is the one with key `itemId`.

Comment: the wanted result is not possible, because it can have only **one** key with the same name.

Comment: @NinaScholz Okay, I've updated the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to iterate the entries, because you have already a key `itemId` for the object.

```
for (let item of this.state.exportEntries) {
    console.log(item);
    if (itemId in item) {
        if (!this.state.filteredData[itemId]) this.state.filteredData[itemId] = item[itemID];
        else this.state.filteredData[itemId] += ', ' + item[itemID];
    }
}

console.log(this.state.filteredData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. This gives me the exact output that I'm needing.